# Using Laravel core in scripts built without it

Tags: ckeditor, laravel, laravel-3, kcfinder

I have built a Laravel 3 application, it involves a lot of per-user content management.

For prototype and internal testing I got away with plain configuration of [KCFinder](http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/), now we're about to start a closed beta.

Firstly, I must lock the **KCFinder** behind Laravel applications Auth system.
Secondly, I must configure the KCF with a per-user settings.

While it may seem like those are two questions, I doubt they are.

---

My Laravel is installed in `/srv/http/`, KCFinder in `/srv/http/public/php/kcfinder/`.

KCFinder exposes two incoming files - `browse.php` and `upload.php`. These files include `core/autoload.php`, that ultimately ties the KCF together.

I tried requiring Laravel's `public/index.php` inside it, then tried to access something KCF (`/php/kcfinder/browse.php`) through browser. Got redirected to a mix of the request path and Laravel applications root route: `/php/kcfinder/browser`.

How could I prevent the Routing from Laravel and be able to use Laravel inside the KCF scope?

P.S. I did try to go the Bundle way, but apparently KCF is so poorly written that it appears that in order to Bundle it up, I'll have to rewrite everything there.

Comment: While I have answered it and got it to work, I will leave the Q open for some time. Maybe someone from Laravel core team could give some insight.

Comment: are you using arch linux ?

Comment: do you use ckfinder  + kcfinder for Laravel 4 ? I am also using Arch but trying to find a nice solution for photo uploads in ckfinder.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the combo of CK + KC.

Comment: I use both. My kcfinder.php is : "'uploadURL' => "/uploads/photo/'.$post->id",
    'uploadDir' => ""   ".I can see that photo in the folder "  "/public/uploads/photo/images" ".The folder I want to upload is "/public/uploads/img/posts/$postId" how can I define $post->id. can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Ask a question, state the problem, show what you've done, I and others of the community will take a look at it, hopefully we'll have an answer and will provide it.

Comment: Hello again , I asked my question but no answers. I am looking a way to POST $post->id.if you have time can you give a short look on it ?  here is my question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316121/how-to-customize-upload-folder-for-ckeditorkcfinder-using-in-laravel. Sorry to disturb you again. Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with a very, very dirty hack.

In `/srv/http/public/php/kcfinder/core/autoload.php` I appended the lines:

```
require '../../../paths.php';

require path('sys').'core.php';

\Laravel\Bundle::start(DEFAULT_BUNDLE);

$KCFinderRoot = addslashes(realpath(dirname(__FILE__). '/../') . DS);

\Laravel\Autoloader::map(array(
    'browser' => $KCFinderRoot . 'core/browser.php',
    'uploader' => $KCFinderRoot . 'core/uploader.php',
    'type_img' => $KCFinderRoot . 'core/types/type_img.php',
    'type_mime' => $KCFinderRoot . 'core/types/type_mime.php',
    'gd' => $KCFinderRoot . 'lib/class_gd.php',
    'input' => $KCFinderRoot . 'lib/class_input.php',
    'zipFolder' => $KCFinderRoot . 'lib/class_zipFolder.php',
    'dir' => $KCFinderRoot . 'lib/helper_dir.php',
    'file' => $KCFinderRoot . 'lib/helper_file.php',
    'httpCache' => $KCFinderRoot . 'lib/helper_httpCache.php',
    'path' => $KCFinderRoot . 'lib/helper_path.php',
    'text' => $KCFinderRoot . 'lib/helper_text.php',
));

if (!\Laravel\Auth::check())
{
    die('no user :(');
}
```

Wherever KCF had some file inclusions, I had to squeeze in `$KCFinderRoot`, in some methods even requiring to `global` them before.

In KCF's config I added:

```
// ...
'uploadURL' => "/useruploads/" . sha1(Auth::user()->id . Auth::user()->email),
'uploadDir' => path('public') . "useruploads/" . sha1(Auth::user()->id . Auth::user()->email),
// ...
```

The end result works like I wanted it to, except I have no idea how "smart" this is.

P.S. In the following days I'm going to try to bundle, IoC this up while leaving KCF files intact.